# Asp.Net MVC route exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC to develop my website. I am getting the following errors.

URL:**http://www.abc.com/robots.txt**
1. The controller for path '/robots.txt' was not found or does not implement IController.

URL:**http://www.abc.com/blogs/post/whats-new-in-mvc**
2. The controller for path '/blogs/post/whats-new-in-mvc' was not found or does not implement IController..

But i dont have the above mentioned url in my website. How the above url are generated? Can you please let me know the solution to fix the above issue?

Comment: Could you show your routing configuration from Global.asax?

Comment: My route configuration is below.                    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is used by search engines to index your website. It's a good practice to have a [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to your application. So you could add this file to the root of your site. As far as the second url is concerned, I have strictly no idea who is querying it. Maybe somewhere inside your site you have a link to this url?

But if you don't want to use this file you could exclude it from routing:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("robots.txt");
```

Now when a search engine sends a request to this file he will also get a 404 but the request won't be routed through the MVC pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Some of the URL are generated automatically which are not related to my website. Do you have any idea how those links are generated?
For ex:www.abc.com/dhsj

Comment: No, I have no idea. Could be hackers or automated bots sending requests to crawl your website attempting to gather more information about the technology being used, ... You could exclude urls from routing using the IgnoreRoute.

Comment: Can you please let me know about automated bots?

Comment: When i search my website in google the invalid links are listed?
Ex:www.abc.com/sample/silverlight
Can you please let me know how it is happened?